# Usage with FFMPEG on a vServer?

Tags: video, ffmpeg

Heyo!

I'm just setting up a video platform for a small project. So far a user is able to upload a video in any common format. The video will be converted using FFMPEG.

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vcodec h264 -acodec aac -strict -2 output.mp4
```

At the moment I'm testing all the stuff on my 3€ testserver which is actually pretty slow. But imagine, a 10 seconds 60fps full hd video takes like 6 minutes of converting. I think I'm not able to run this configurations on a live version. :D

My current test setup:
vCPU 1x (Events per second: ~175)

So my question is, which cpu should I use? I searched for a server on hetzner. The setup with dedicated vCPU is especially declared for video converting. But the cpu benchmark is not much better with ~600 events per second while the price is around 20€.

What do I need to convert a 10 min video (full hd 60fps) in just 1-2 minutes? My budget should be around ~30€/m.

Comment: Get the most powerful CPU you can afford, or investigate using an instance with a GPU and encoding with nevenc or similar. (And remove `-strict -2`: you don't need that since it's no longer 2015.)

Comment: Thanks for your reply I really appreciate it. What is especially importand regarding CPU? Is it more cores or more GHz? I'll try to find an alternative hoster with GPU but I think it would be more expansive. :D

Comment: Too many variables to give you a yes/no answer regarding GHz vs cores. I recommend trying a few of the different vCPU levels (they may only charge you per hour if Hetzner is like some of the hosts I've tried) and doing some benchmarks yourself.